# How to Assign a TBitmap to a TPath.Data

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, tbitmap

I would like to fill a TPath.Data from a TBitmap.

Delphi FMX provides a FillPath on a Bitmap Canvas:-
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Rio/en/FMXTCanvasFillFunctions_(Delphi)

Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.FillPath(path, 200);

But I'm looking fill the Path Data from the Bitmap.

Any code examples?
tia

Comment: Isn't that exactly what your line of code is already doing?

Comment: @Matthias. No, as per the link provided the example:- procedure TForm3.RadioButton13Click(Sender: TObject);    // fills and draws the path on the canvas

Comment: It is unclear what do you want - you already have example.

Comment: As explained. The opposite of Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.FillPath(path, 200);

Comment: In order to fill the path data from a Bitmap you would need to vectorize your Bitmap. Since this is a rather complex process that may need even manual adaptations there is no automatic way to do this in Delphi.

Comment: iamjoosy is right. You will have to analyse your image mathematically to extract some form of polygon or spline that you can use to fill your TPath.Data. This is not a trivial task. A brief introduction with some code can be found here: http://cardhouse.com/computer/vector.htm. Google "raster to vector" for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You mean how do you fill an enclosed TPath with a bitmap instead of a solid color. You change the Fill property to a Bitmap:

```
path1.Fill.Bitmap:=mybitmap;
path1.Fill.Kind:=TBrushKind.Bitmap;
```

Comment: Hi Doug. Using path1.Fill.Bitmap:=mybitmap; The Path1.Data is still empty. i.e. if Path1.Data.IsEmpty then
    ShowMessage('Path Data is Empty');  Path1.Data is what I'm trying to populate from a Bitmap and then reassign. Thanks

Comment: Populate Path1.Data from Bitmap doesn't make sense. Path.Data is a series of points. A bitmap has no points. Unless you have some image recognition software that recognizes a picture of a house and extracts points from it.